# Sam build failed for nodejs 10.x runtime is not supported

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-serverless, aws-sam-cli

i have ubuntu **v18.10** , with aws cli Version: **0.14.2**,

i am not able to run

sam build
command , it gives error

```
Building resource 'TestFunction' 
Build Failed Error:
'nodejs10.x' runtime is not supported
```

Comment: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/8627

Answer (score 1):

I am running the latest version of SAM on Windows (0.37.0) and nodejs10.x is still not supported.  Lambda has support for nodejs 10 and 12 now, plus 8.10 is deprecated.  So, the SAM team has still not updated their tooling yet.  A look at the Lambda api docs show support for the following:

> Runtime
>      The identifier of the function's runtime.
>      Required: Yes
>      Type: String
>      Allowed Values: dotnetcore1.0 | dotnetcore2.1 | go1.x | java11 | java8 | nodejs10.x | nodejs12.x | nodejs8.10 | provided | python2.7 | python3.6 | python3.7 | python3.8 | ruby2.5